# Difference between the SQL Server Docker Images?

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-aks

I see the following docker images are available for SQL Server:

- mssql-server-linux/mssql-server-linux
- mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mssql-server-linux/mssql-server-linux` is the *old* [deprecated](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) docker image.

`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04` is the Ubuntu 18.04 based Docker image for SQL Server 2019, and includes CU4; the latest version is CU6. See the official Microsoft Docker page here: [Microsoft SQL Server - Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)